# Delphi: BytesToRaw ломает переменную в клиенте, а на сервере норм

Tags: delphi, indy

Вот что делаю на сервере (TPing - record):

```
Buffer := RawToBytes(Settings, SizeOf(Settings)); //settings: TPing
BytesToRaw(Buffer, test, sizeof(test)); //test: TPing
ShowMessage(test.map); //Выводит тоже что и в settings.map, т.е. успешно переданы данные.
AContext.Connection.Socket.Write(Buffer);
```

Потом в клиенте:

```
IdTCPClient.Socket.ReadBytes(Buffer, SizeOf(ping)); //В дебаги точно такой же массив, что и на сервере
BytesToRaw(Buffer, ping, sizeof(ping)); //ping: TPing
ShowMessage(ping.map); //Выводит пустоту, а в дебаге Inaccessible value
```

TPing хранится в отдельном unit, который подключается к серверу и клиенту

Comment: Покажите объявление `TPing`. Подозреваю, что вы пытаетесь передать строку и делаете это неправильно.

Comment: Вот где собака зарыта. Спасибо, вы были правы, у меня был string простой, сделал string[32] стало все норм.

Comment: @MrLuckyTomas я бы не сказал, что `string[32]` это хорошее решение. Да, это дает возможность загрузить record в буфер одной операцией. Но вы заранее ограничили себя только ANSI-кодировкой и жестко заданным размером...